# How to out of while and for loop combined

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, combinations

I am trying to write a code that is capturing number 3. using while loop as the condition, so that the for statement will be the evaluation condition of $x, of the while loop statement, and by the same time, using if statement to evaluate the value of $x=3 and so it can **echo 'three..';** . please enlighten me. thank you

```
<?php
$x = 0;
$y = 5;

while ($x <= $y) {
    for ($z = 0; $z < 3; $z++) {
        if ($x = 3) {
            echo 'three..' . "\n";
        }
    }
    $y++;
}
```

Comment: `echo 'now x is ' . $z . "\n";` Why would `x` be `$z`? You never change `$x`

Comment: The while statement condition is always true because in logic there is no x increment, only y increment.

Comment: Are you certain this loop runs? Because `$x` will be `<= $y` from the start

Comment: @brombeer - It should definitely run.... for eternity...

Comment: Question is unclear, why have `for` and `while`? Is https://3v4l.org/Q9YJt what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes I certainly do, this is actually run, I have change $z to $x, but still it keeps looping forever,  never get out of while loop, i think the while loop is causing it.

Comment: _"I have change $z to $x"_ - [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71032011/edit) your question and add your change at the end so we can see how you actually changed it. And the fact that it is running for ever is clear. The loop will continue as long as `$x` is less or equal to `$y`. Since `$x` starts as less then `$y` and your code only increases `$y`, that condition will _always_ be true.

Comment: `if ($x = 3)` should be `if ($x == 3)`. Just having one `=` means that you assign a value to a variable. You need `==` or `===` to compare a variable with a value. However, this changes nothing of the initial problem. Still an infinite loop.

Comment: @M. Eriksson ok thank you sir. that solved my problem

Comment: @M.Eriksson Well ... yes, of course, not sure what I was thinking. Let's blame the lack of caffeine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In while loop, you should increment **x variable**.
If you increment **y variable**, it will always **"true"**. So it will be endless loop.

```
<?php
 $x = 0;
 $y = 5;

while ($x <= $y) {
   // code
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = 0;
$y = 5;

while ($x <= $y) {
    for ($z = 0; $z < 3; $z++) {
        echo $z;
    }
        if ($x == 3) {
            echo 'three..' . "\n";
        }
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add an explanation to your post rather then just code blocks. If this is the solution, please explain why or how you solved it.